# How to convert a specific event handler arrow function and use .bind

Tags: bind, arrow-functions

I'm new to React and I'm trying to convert this arrow function into a function to bind with this. I already tried using this guide (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb) but wasn't successful.

Any help / explanation would be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
toggleComplete(index) {
      const todos = this.state.todos.slice();
      const todo = todos[index];
      todo.isCompleted = todo.isCompleted ? false : true;
      this.setState({ todos: todos });
    }
```

....

Full code is here: https://codeshare.io/2pw0q0

Within the calling of the  component, I tried to change

```
toggleComplete={ () => this.toggleComplete(index)}
```

into:

```
toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete}
```

and to add

```
this.toggleComplete=this.toggleComplete.bind(this)
```

below the constructor() function. But it didn't work out.

Comment: Any luck?  Awaiting your response.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you should bind `toggleComplete` when setting state

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    todos: [
      { description: 'Walk the cat', isCompleted: true, isDeleted: false },
      { description: 'Throw the dishes away', isCompleted: false, isDeleted: false },
      { description: 'Buy new dishes', isCompleted: false, isDeleted: false }
    ],
    newTodoDescription: '',
    this.toggleComplete: this.toggleComplete.bind(this)
  };
}
```

Also I think your logic may be off for toggling todos.  When setting the function in your class maybe do something like this.

```
toggleComplete(index) {
  const { todos } = this.state;
  const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo, idx) => {
    if (idx === index) {
       todo.isCompleted = !todo.isCompleted
    }
  }
  this.setState({ todos: updatedTodos });
}
```

In your render method

```
toggleComplete={this.toggleComplete}
index={index}
```

It appears you're passing your `toggleComplete` function down and actually calling it on the `ToDo` component, no?  If so pass down your `index` and `toggleComplete` as props and then you can call `toggleComplete` on your `ToDo` component. Make sure to use an arrow function like `onClick={() => this.props.toggleComplete(index)}` when setting it or it will get called every time your component gets re-rendered.